# How to change the margin of only the first page in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a report in Word using Excel. I want the margin of the first page in the word file to be custom and from second page onwards I want the page margins to be some other value. All these values are user defined somewhere. How do I put different margins through VBA when I am not able to track if a second page is even created in the word Report.
Sorry if this feels repeated but all the existing similar questions I saw were not exactly fitting in.

Comment: This tool is handy for [printing multiple pages with multiple setups](https://chandoo.org/wp/hui%E2%80%99s-excel-report-printer/).

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more intuitive if it's only the first page you need to edit, to simply change the margin manually (space it out)? Will save you some time and some unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: Rawrplus- Well True, but this is a part of the tool which is to be given to someone else and It's kind of part of the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Word manually, you would insert a Next Page Section Break after the first page content, and then change the margins in the layout in the new section. In Word VBA this would be like:

```
' First page content..
....

'New section on new page        
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
With Selection.PageSetup
    .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(<new margin>)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(<new margin>)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(<new margin>)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(<new margin>)
    .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    '...other page set-up
End With
```